# swipeEnabled prop of nested TabNavigator inside Stack Navigator(React Navigation) crashes the app in IOS emulator when set to true

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

```js
const NavBar = TabNavigator({
  HamburgerMenu: {
    screen: HamburgerScreen,
    navigationOptions: { 
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name='bars' style={styles.iconStyle}/>
    }    
  },
  Landing: {
    screen: LandingScreen,
    navigationOptions: { 
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name='home' style={styles.iconStyle}/>
      
    }   
  },
  SearchMenu: {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    navigationOptions: { 
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name='search' style={styles.iconStyle}/>
      
    }   
  },
  CategoryMenu: {
    screen: CategoryScreen,
    navigationOptions: { 
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name='th-large' style={styles.iconStyle}/>
      
    }   
  },
  NotificationMenu: {
    screen: NotificationScreen,
    navigationOptions: { 
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name='bell-o' style={styles.iconStyle}/>
      
    }   
  },
  InboxMenu: {
    screen: InboxScreen,
    navigationOptions: { 
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name='comments' style={styles.iconStyle} />,
      tabBarVisible: false  
    }   
  },

}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled:true,  
    initialRouteName: 'Landing',  
    tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel:false,
    tinColor: '#405ac2',
    activeTintColor: '#eee',
    upperCaseLabel: true,
    indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ccc'
    },
    style: {
        backgroundColor: "#405ac2"
    },
    tabStyle : {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
}
  ,
}

);
```

I am building a react-native application using react-navigation and this is my code for TabNavigator(nested inside StackNavigator) where swipe gesture for switching between the tabs works well on android but is not working on ios emulator.So I used swipeEnabled:true in my tabbar config but the app crashes due to it.

Thanks in Advance!